# Trouble understanding $\sum$ notation

Tags: notation, summation

**Question:**

> What does $$\left(\sum_{a, b, c}a\right)^2$$ mean ?

The answer given is $(a+b+c)^2$. However, I am having trouble understanding this.

I have seen [this](http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/QQ/database/QQ.09.00/daniel1.html), [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zg-gxekFIA8) and [this](http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/sigma-notation.html). But none helped.

Please help me understand this.

**EDIT**:

Also, what would be a better way to write:

$$\sum_{a,b,c}(b-c)(b+c)$$

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know who produced such rubbish, but nobody can blame you for not understanding it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation is very bad, since the summation index is apparently named $a$, while $a$ is also one of the values it takes. Better notations for this would be
$$
\left(\sum_{k=a,b,c} k\right)^2\quad\text{or}\quad\left(\sum_{k\in\{a,b,c\}} k\right)^2.
$$
Here the summation index is explicitly labeled $k$ and it takes values $a$, $b$ and $c$, so the sum is $a+b+c$.

The sum in the edit is even worse, I can't tell you what it means. I'd say it is just wrong. Summations should come with a summation index, always.

---

In the comments you mentioned that they call these summations *cyclic expression*, which does indeed help at *guessing* what it's supposed to be. Consider the summand $(b-c)(b+c)$ as an expression in $a,b,c$ and then look at the same term for the cyclic permutations $b,c,a$ and $c,a,b$. So I *guess* they want
$$
\sum_{a,b,c}(b-c)(b+c) = (b-c)(b+c) + (c-a)(c+a) + (a-b)(a+b).
$$

Comment: So, I conclude that these are just bad notations. I wonder if I should have bought this book.

Comment: Does the book tell you what $\sum_{a,b,c}(b-c)(b+c)$ is supposed to be in their world? Also, which book is it?

Comment: No, it does not. The book is [this](http://www.flipkart.com/iit-foundation-olympiad-explorer-class-ix-1st/p/itmdyv7umdhbhafg).

Comment: BTW, they call this summation a cyclic expression, does this help in solving the problem ?

Comment: @GaurangTandon It helps, see my edit, but I still wouldn't recommend using such notations without further explanation anywhere.

Comment: Superb guess! That's what they wanted. Thanks for the explanation :)